# Jquery UI Inline Calendar Multiple Rows

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

https://jsfiddle.net/gg2x5d9h/

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="list-year"></div>
</div>
$( "#list-year" ).datepicker({
               numberOfMonths: 12,
            });
```

How do I make it so it has 3 columns
and 4 rows?

Comment: what do you mean by **4 columns and 4 rows** ? Is it in calendar or a month on a div and there have 4 div?

Comment: *"4 columns and 4 rows"* - How would a 4x4 grid work for selecting a date? Years don't have 16 months; months don't have 16 days...

Comment: I don't need to select date.
I just want to display some dates that is booked. this is for booking website.

Comment: If you just want to display dates why are you using a `datepicker`? Please [edit] your question to explain clearly where the data is coming from, and to show a sample of the desired output.

Comment: I have seen a website that utilizes jquery ui datepicker in order to accomplish what I want.
but I don't how did they do it

Answer (score 1):

```
$( "#list-year" ).datepicker({
   numberOfMonths: [ 4, 3 ]
});
```

Found the solution in the documentation.

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/